# MVVM WPF to implement Find and FindNext in dataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, telerik

Consider DataGrid is loaded and when find clicked first match is selected and 
[image: For Find]

On FindNext next match is highlighted

Note : I am able to implement in Normal WPF, But in MVVM we should not pass GRID/Grid cell Object to ViewModel, So not able to change the style of particular Area on Button click.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Find your results in the VM, express them as models bound to the UI, and in the UI perform your UI tasks of interpreting the models, locating the UI elements to be updated, and update them.  Tada.

Answer (score -1):

How I solved this problem:

```
private List<v_Repairs> searchRepairs = new List<v_Repairs>();
int searchCount = 0;
int searchPosition = 0; 
private string searchText;
        public string SearchText
        {
            get { return searchText; }
            set
            {
                searchText = value;
                RaisedPropertyChanged("SearchText");
            }
        }
 private ICommand searchCommand;
        public ICommand SearchCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (searchCommand == null)
                {
                    searchCommand = new RelayCommand(new Action<object>(Search));
                }
                return searchCommand;
            }
            set
            {
                searchCommand = value;
                RaisedPropertyChanged("SearchCommand");
            }
        }
        public void Search(object Parameter)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SearchText))
            {
                searchPosition = 0;
                searchRepairs = V_Repairs.Where(r => r.Serial_Number.Contains(SearchText)).ToList();
                searchCount = searchRepairs.Count;
                SelectedItem = (v_Repairs)searchRepairs[0];
                searchPosition++;
            }
        }
 private ICommand searchNextCommand;
        public ICommand SearchNextCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (searchNextCommand == null)
                {
                    searchNextCommand = new RelayCommand(new Action<object>(SearchNext));
                }
                return searchNextCommand;
            }
            set
            {
                searchNextCommand = value;
                RaisedPropertyChanged("SearchNextCommand");
            }
        }
        public void SearchNext(object Parameter)
        {
            if (searchRepairs.Count > 0)
            {
                if (searchRepairs[0].Serial_Number.Contains(SearchText))
                {
                    if (searchPosition < searchRepairs.Count)
                    {
                        SelectedItem = (v_Repairs)searchRepairs[searchPosition];
                        searchPosition++;
                    }
                    else if (searchPosition == searchRepairs.Count)
                    {
                        SelectedItem = (v_Repairs)searchRepairs[0];
                        searchPosition = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        searchPosition = 0;
                        searchCount = 0;
                        searchRepairs.Clear();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```